# Tiny White Box Displaying only in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

White Box issue only when using Chrome this box does not display in any other browser.
Anyone know of any Css tricks to get rid of it? Funny thing is it displays only for 3-4
seconds and goes away very annoying tho.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? It is very unclear what you are talking about.

Comment: It's a website I'm currently working on I do have an image of the problem but no way to display it on here. It's basically a mini-cart that pops up when a user adds to cart within the mini cart display a tiny white box pops up for a couple seconds and then fades away only in chrome.

Answer (score -1):

It may just be a bug with your browser, have you tried restarting your browser? Also make sure that you didn't leave something in your HTML on accident.